# Java - Implementing my own Stream

Tags: java, stream, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to implement a custom Stream?
I would like to create a StringStream in addition to IntStream or LongStream.

I would like to add extra methods, like storeToFile(path).

I thought it is a lot of work to implement a Stream. The standard implementation is java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline, but I cannot instantiate it directy. 
Is there a simple solution?

Thanks for help.

Comment: A StringStream already exists. It's a Stream<String>.

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: Yes, but I would like to add extra methods. For example storeToFile(String: path).

Comment: Stream is an interface. So, yes, you can create a class that implements that interface, or create an interface that extends Stream. It's no different from any other interface.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a `Collector` that is custom, not a Stream. You can create a `Stream` out of anything with `Stream.of()`, but you would need collectors for this.

`storeToFile` would be a StoringToFileCollector or something...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can create a stream of anything you want.

Extend the interface [`BaseStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html)

```
public interface MyStream extends BaseStream<MyClass,MyStream>
```

Then implement it

```
public class DefaultMyStream implements MyStream
{
    //...
}
```

Probably crosscheck another stream implementation when writing your implementation.

---

I don't know that there's necessarily a huge advantage to doing this. Maybe there's a valid use case. In any case, it's possible.

Comment: I thought it is a lot of work to implement a Stream. The standard implementation is java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline, but I cannot instantiate it directy. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: You're almost certainly right but that's not what you asked. It sounds like you should either create a new question or heavily edit this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.